# Rename tag sprint-test-dbunit - typo in name

Tags: support, tags

I've just realized that there's a typo in the tag [sprint-test-dbunit](/questions/tagged/sprint-test-dbunit) and it should be [spring-test-dbunit](/questions/tagged/spring-test-dbunit) instead.  Letter G at the end of spring instead of letter T.

How do I correct this?

Comment: You can just edit the tag directly on the question when you see something like this; if it's on 0 questions it will be automatically deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. Voted to close one of them though...

There were only two so I edited them; you can do this in the future should you wish (and you're certain). If you're not 100% sure or there's lots of questions ask on meta.